# Why i got this error trying to run nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, visual-studio-code, console

This error does not goes away! and it shows only in the VScode output console, I run the code in google chrome and the error is gone.

ReferenceError: document is not defined

```
    [Running] node "c:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\MEGAsync\Code\JavasScript\11-Arrays-Bankist\starter\script.js"
c:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\MEGAsync\Code\JavasScript\11-Arrays-Bankist\starter\script.js:95
const labelWelcome = document.querySelector('.welcome');
                     ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\MEGAsync\Code\JavasScript\11-Arrays-Bankist\starter\script.js:95:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.12.1

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.217 seconds
```

Comment: Because Chrome is a browser it understands what a `document` is. NodeJS does not.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a JavaScript runtime environment, but that does not mean that it has access to all the same APIs a web browser might have. The [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document) global is not available in Node.js, but only in web browsers.

Comment: So how can make him to get access to my document?

Comment: You can't, Node.js doesn't have a [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).